# R Cairo package installation failed in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04

I attempt to install Cairo package in R under a Docker Ubuntu 18.04 container. Before installing the R Cairo package, I installed these packets in Ubuntu:　libgtk2.0-dev, libcairo2-dev, xvfb, xauth, xfonts-base, r-base-dev, and libxt-dev.

However, when I installed Cairo package in R, I got the following error:

```
checking if R was compiled with the RConn patch... no
checking cairo.h usability... yes
checking cairo.h presence... yes
checking for cairo.h... yes
checking for PNG support in Cairo... yes
checking for ATS font support in Cairo... no
configure: CAIRO_LIBS=-lfreetype -lz -lpng16 -lz -lcairo -lXext -lXrender -lX11
checking for library containing deflate... no
checking whether Cairo programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot 
compile a simple Cairo program. See config.log for details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Cairo’
* removing ‘/opt/conda/lib/R/library/Cairo’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmprETcPh/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("Cairo") :
  installation of package ‘Cairo’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've checked /tmp/RtmprETcPh/downloaded_packages, and there is only a filed called Cairo_1.5-9.tar.gz. And I don't know where to find config.log for more compile details of compiling a simple Cairo program.

Please help me to resolve out this issue if anybody know how to resolve out this issue.

Thank you

Comment: `sudo apt install r-cran-cairo` -- it is part of bionic as you can see [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-cran-cairo).

Comment: I tried `sudo apt install r-cran-cairo`, but the problem still remains

Comment: After installing `r-cran-cairo ` you don’t need to install the package anymore. It will be part of your R installation!

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I need to change to the user who uses R first, and then execute `sudo apt install r-cran-cairo`

Comment: No that will be a system-wide installation automatically available for all users---just like the other thousands on Ubuntu packages on your system.

Comment: It seems my R project accesses to a different directory. The Cairo package is installed in `/usr/lib/R/site-library/Cairo`; but my project accesses to `/usr/local/lib/opencpu/site-library` and `/opt/conda/lib/R/library`

Answer (score 3):

You may need to install the x11 dev libs since the docker container is likely not running these.
Try

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

Comment: `libx11-dev` is installed, but I still cannot install Cairo in R.

Comment: Per https://salsa.debian.org/r-pkg-team/r-cran-cairo/blob/master/debian/control you need `libcairo2-dev` and `libxt-dev`. But see my earlier comment: you do *not need* to build from source once you install `r-cran-cairo`.

Answer (score 0):

Under ubuntu 20.04, after installing libx11-dev, trying to install Cairo gave the error X11/Intrinsic.h not found. This is in libxt-dev. After installing this, Cairo could be installed.